# How to reset/rerender screen you just left with react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

So, exactly what the title says, I'm making a react native app and I want the screen that I leave with `navigation.navigate()` to be "reset" or "rerendered" when I come back to it, because as it is now, when I leave the screen and then come back to it it's state is the same as I left it. Here's the navigator code

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Group>
        <Tab.Screen name="Devices" component={Devices} options={{
          tabBarIcon:({focused})=>(
            <View style={{alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
              <Image
                source={require('./android/app/src/main/assets/devices.png')}
                resizeMode='contain'
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30
                }}
              />
            </View>
          )
        }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Connection" component={ConnectionScreen} options={{
          tabBarIcon:({focused})=>(
            <View style={{alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
              <Image
                source={require('./android/app/src/main/assets/connection.png')}
                resizeMode='contain'
                style={{
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30
                }}
              />
            </View>
          )
        }} />
        </Tab.Group>
        <Tab.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
          <Tab.Screen name='Add device' component={AddDevice}
          options={{   
            tabBarButton: () => null,
            tabBarVisible:false
          }}/>
        </Tab.Group>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And the second smaller thing is, that I can't see any navigation aniamtions, like this Modal on the bottom for example

Comment: you can change one state result . as you know when state result changed screen will rerender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `unmountOnBlur` to `true`

> Unmounting a screen resets any local state in the screen as well as the state of the nested navigators in the screen. Defaults to `false`.

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{ unmountOnBlur: true }}
>
...
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Also, you can apply it to a single route:

```
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="..." component={...} options={{ unmountOnBlur: true }} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Do you perhaps also know why I can't see aimations when changing screens like the modal screen at the bottom, the example on the react navigations site didn't have anything diferent in it, and it worked on snack expo https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/

Comment: You are using Tab navigator which doesn't have animation. The example you provided using Stack navigator however you can nest a Stack navigator inside a Tab navigator. see more: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

Comment: Thanks man, after months I had given up on finding a solution, and by pure chance I found your answers, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of **useIsFocused**, try something like:

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

useEffect(() => {
    //executes whenever this component/screen is focused
  }, [isFocused]);
```

You can also set the **unmountOnBlur** flag to true to the particular screen as below:

```
<Tab.Screen
    name={...}
    component={...}
    options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}
/>
```